# Replacing the webpage with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTML Agility Pack to parse a webpage to pull certain tags and haven't run into many problems so far. What i'm trying to achieve overall is to transform the webpage depending on a condition, eg. press and button and change the content.

So far i've got as far as changing the Html Document nodes to how i want them and saving them locally as a .txt file just to see if they change as they should, which they do.

Now, my question is; Can i use HTML agility pack to push this new HTML document and change what the user sees? And if not, how should i approach it?

Eg. Original content is..

```
            <p> Hi </p>
            <p> Whats up </p>
```

When they click a button it should change to:

```
            <p> You clicked</p>
            <p> The button </p>
```

Like i said, i already have the transforming done, it's just pushing that to the browser that i'm trying to get done.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not how you design a webpage. For instance if you have one user who presses the button, then the webpage will change for all the next visitors who vistit that page. It's not like everyone keeps a copy of your website on their computer.

You need to use asp.NET